# iOS MFMailComposeViewController and getting users Name from contact card

Tags: ios, email, contacts, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, abaddressbook

I want to get the "Me" card's Name so when i create the mail window with MFMailComposeViewController

I can

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailer setSubject:@"Suggestion: from (Name of Person)"];
```

Basically substitute the (Name of Person) with the name on their contact card.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3747877/529363)

Comment: I know how 2 get all contacts. how do I determine if the contact card is "Me" (owner of the device).

Comment: Maybe a better approach would be getting it from device name, it's not  a perfect method but it's the best i [found](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/getting-the-iphone-user-name.html).

Comment: the device name usually has the person's name but it's not always the case. It will look dumb saying "Suggestion from iPhone 5" instead of "Suggestion from John Doe"

Comment: I know, but it is the closest solution I found, that's why I've posted it just as a comment ;)

Comment: I like your suggestion @ender , do you have working code that can demonstrate this?

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261961/better-way-to-get-the-users-name-from-device)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the "Me" card from the iOS SDK. There's a `me` method [for the mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ABAddressBook), but not for iOS. If the name of the person will be in the From: field, what value is there in adding it to the subject line?

Comment: Some people have weird names (which aren't their real names). Some poeple just have no names and just an email address xyz@abc.com. There is many variations for the from field. I was hoping to make it easy for the receptionist when she gets the emails, she can sort by Subject and see the name quicker.