# Any way to get the name of iPhone user?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uidevice

Outside of asking the user to input their name, is there any way to get it off the device?

I tried this library, which attempts to extract the name from `[UIDevice currentDevice] name]`, but that doesn't work in a lot of situations:

https://github.com/tiboll/TLLNameFromDevice

Is the user's name present in the phonebook or anywhere else that we have access to in iOS 6?

Comment: I don't think it's possible on iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12715598/1813169

Answer (score 12):

Well you could go through all the contacts in the AddressBook and see if any of them are marked with the owner flag.

Just be aware that doing this will popup the "this app wants access to the address book" message. Also Apple isn't very keen on these kind of things. In the app review guide it is specified that an app can not use personal information without the user's permission.

Comment: Finally an answer that doesn't immediately repeat the lazy "it's impossible" non-answer... (+1)

Comment: Where is this owner flag?

Comment: @rckoenes, please elaborate on this 'owner' flag. Some example code would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You could use [Square's solution](http://www.quora.com/Square-Inc-1/How-does-Square-know-my-name-in-their-apps-registration-process):

1. [Get the device's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100127/how-do-you-get-an-iphones-device-name) (e.g. "John Smith's iPhone").
2. Go through the contacts on the phone and look for a contact named "John Smith".

[JBDeviceOwner](https://github.com/jakeboxer/JBDeviceOwner) and [ABGetMe](https://github.com/0xced/ABGetMe) will both do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/cloudkit-storage/). Following a snippet in Swift (ignoring errors):

```
let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()

container.fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler(
    {
        (recordID, error) in

        container.requestApplicationPermission(
            .PermissionUserDiscoverability,
            {
                (status, error2) in

                if (status == CKApplicationPermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    container.discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID(
                        recordID,
                        completionHandler:
                        {
                            (info, error3) in

                            println("\(info.firstName) \(info.lastName)")
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
)
```

The above code was based on the code at http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/109633/CloudKit-User-Info

to save folks time. in swift4:

```
    let container = CKContainer.default()
    container.fetchUserRecordID(
        completionHandler: {
            (recordID, error) in
            guard let recordID = recordID else {
                return
            }
            container.requestApplicationPermission(
                .userDiscoverability,
                completionHandler: {
                    (status, error2) in

                    if (status == CKContainer_Application_PermissionStatus.granted)
                    {
                        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                            container.discoverUserIdentity(withUserRecordID:
                                recordID,
                                                           completionHandler:
                                {
                                    (info, error3) in
                                    guard let info = info else {
                                        return
                                    }
                                    print("\(info.firstName) \(info.lastName)")
                            }
                            )
                        }
                    }
            }
            )
        }
    )
```

however: CKUserIdentity no longer exposes either first or last name

So this answer no longer works.

Comment: It should be noted that, if this permission has not already been granted, this will prompt the user for permission to let himself be discoverable by others users of the same app who have his email address in their address book.

Comment: When I try this, I get the error message: Type CKApplicationsPermissions has no member 'PermissionUserDiscoverability'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
NSLog(@"user == %@",[[[NSHost currentHost] names] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

I did receive compiler warnings that the methods `+currentHost` and `-names` were not found. Given the warning, I’m not sure of Apple’s intention to make this available (or not) as a publicly accessible API, however, everything seemed to work as expected without the need to include any additional header files or linking in additional `libraries`/`frameworks`.

**Edit 1:**
You may also take a look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3747877/1091539)

**Edit 2:**
If you have integrated your app with Facebook you can easily retrieve the user info, see [Facebook Fetch User Data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/user-data-ios-sdk/)

Answer (score -2):

For SWIFT you can use

[`NSUserName()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1414297-nsusername) returns the logon name of the current user.

```html
func NSUserName() -> String
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: this returns `"mobile"`