# is device owner always part of user address book

Tags: ios, iphone

I was wondering if "device owner is always part of addressbook of the phone as a contact"?

I want to get user name and photo automagically if "user has allowed access to its addressbook"?

I did follow this [Any way to get the name of iPhone user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897605/any-way-to-get-the-name-of-iphone-user)

Comment: I wouldn't make such an assumption.

Comment: @rmaddy  Thanks...I thought so...does ios provide any such api even if it requires user to give permissions? or the best design would be to ask users only?

Comment: API for what? To get the name of device owner? No, there is no such thing.