# How to get the user "Name" using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create an app that when the user open the first view it will provide with a nice greeting.

For example depending on the time of the day it would say "Good Morning/Afternoon/Night - User Name".

How do I get the name that the User has on his iPhone? I need the name that is on `Settings > General > About _ NAME`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get an iPhone's device name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100127/how-do-you-get-an-iphones-device-name)

Comment: What you are trying to get is "device" name, not "user" name.

Comment: This may look weird. My iPhone's name (and probably everyone's) is Linus' iPhone. So your app will say "Good morning Linus' iPhone". I don't know if that's so awesome…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to get the user's name from device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261961/better-way-to-get-the-users-name-from-device)

Answer (score 3):

UIDevice.current.name gives back device name, so you should parse the string trying to distinguish between device type (iPhone, iPad and so on...) and the name.
But is  bit tricky: suppose You have "My iPhone" , "Mary's iPhone" or "IPhone of John" or similar.

Soem people try to use regular expressions, but result is not so good, specially for non-english names.
see at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261961/better-way-to-get-the-users-name-from-device

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 2**
UIDevice.currentDevice().name
**Swift 3**
UIDevice.current.name

Answer (score -1):

```
let benutzerGeraeteName = UIDevice.current.name
        print("Hallo, \(benutzerGeraeteName)")
```