# Fetch the Contact from the Device owner

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, owner

How can I identify that the contact is the holder or owner gf the current device. I need the name from the Device owner. Any suggestions ? Thanks my developer friends and stay healthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **`UIDevice`** class:

As an example: `UIDevice.current.name`

Use a UIDevice object to get information about the device such as assigned name, device model, and operating-system name and version.

Offical Documentation: [Apple Developer Documentation > UIDevice Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice)

Comment: Then I only get the Device Name for example iPhone Alex. But I need the completely name of the person not device. For example Alexander Römer

Comment: We can only get the device name and separate the users name from it. For more on getting the username from device name, see this link,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261961/better-way-to-get-the-users-name-from-device